# How create a jwt signature using a private key and a rsasha256 algorithm (.net)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt

I am trying to sign a JWT with a private key and the rsasha256 algorithm. Everytime a try to create the tokenHandler, it goes into the Catch part.

The exception that I get is:

> System.Exception: 'Erro ao obter ID do processo: IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.
> Algorithm: 'System.String', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey'
> is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: [https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms'](https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms%27)

```
        var privateKey = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Cencosud\Git\APIs\Api_Unico\Unico.Infra.Data\API.Services\Implementations\.key.pem");
        privateKey = privateKey.Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty).Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty);
        privateKey = privateKey.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
        var privateKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey);


        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = privateKeyBytes;
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = "service_account_name@tenant_id.iam.acesso.io",
            Audience = "https://identityhomolog.acesso.io",
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
        });


        var jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Answer (score -1):

A couple problems here:

1. The code is converting the private key as if it's a UTF8 string using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. Use `Convert.FromBase64String` instead.
2. The code is attempting to initialize `SigningCredentials` as a symmetric key but a private RSA key isn't symmetrical and needs to be created differently.

See my changes below:

```
var privateKey = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Cencosud\Git\APIs\Api_Unico\Unico.Infra.Data\API.Services\Implementations\.key.pem");
privateKey = privateKey.Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty).Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty);
privateKey = privateKey.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);

// CHANGE CONVERSION TYPE
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);

// INITIALIZE RSA
using var rsa = RSA.Create();
// Since the private key starts with "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" it's PKCS8 encoded
rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Issuer = "service_account_name@tenant_id.iam.acesso.io",
    Audience = "https://identityhomolog.acesso.io",
    // CREATE SIGNING CREDENTIALS WITH THE RSA INITIALIZED ABOVE
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
});

var jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```